# Suddenly can't run sudo

Tags: command-line, mount, permissions, sudo, root

I didn't do anything on the computer except Internet for a few days and suddenly when I tried to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I got:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set
      or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

I have no idea what happened, last time I remember running `sudo` is when I did update.

Comment: Could you [edit] the output of `mount` onto your question please?

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/questions/877967/sudo-fails-when-running-as-service) topic can help

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. error from sudo:
```
effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges
```
Then I check the mounted file system and it is not mounted with nosuid:
```
snappy@rcn-pg-03:~$ df -h /usr/bin/sudo
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root  118G   20G   92G  18% /
snappy@rcn-pg-03:~$ mount | grep rootvg-root
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=112,data=ordered)
snappy@rcn-pg-03:~$
```

Answer (score 11):

`sudo` works with a mechanism that is called **[setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)** (**Set User ID**, or also called **suid**). If that bit is set on an executable file (like `sudo`), then the application is executed under the permissions of the user, who is the owner of that file (in case of `sudo`, the owner is the `root` user).

That means, sudo is executed as `root`. So far so good. But, now nothing prevents you from inserting an USB-drive with a shell on it, that has the setuid bit set. You have full root access! That's why normally USB-drives are mounted with the mount option `noexec`, to prevent executing binary/scripts on such a device. Another mount option, if you still want to execute files, is the one that is mentioned in the error message in your question: `nosuid`.

See that excerpt of the [mount manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/mount.8.html):

> ```
> [...]
> nosuid     Do not allow set-user-identifier or set-group-identifier bits to take effect.
> [...]
> ```

With the `mount` command, you can determine, if your root filesystem is mounted with that option. Just type:

```
$ mount
```

You can now remount the filesystem on-the-fly and change mount options:

```
$ mount -n -o remount,suid /
```

That sets the `suid` option, which is the exact opposite of `nosuid`.

Comment: But how can this happen at sudden, without plugging/unplugging anything (disk/usb e.t.c)?

Answer (score 2):

Not really 100% related, but hear me out:

I had this problem, because I had changed the default Docker installation. And *docker service* wanted to execute `sudo` or do similar things (system calls?)

More specifically, I had moved the filesystem location where Docker installs volumes and images.
Docker Virtual machines  can take a substantial amount of disk space.
Therefore I had moved `/var/lib/docker` to  `/mnt/virtualmachines_ssd/docker`.

After a while I had forgotten that. I had to find out where `/var/lib/docker` was symlinked to.

```
ls -l /var/lib/docker
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  /var/lib/docker -> /mnt/virtualmachines_ssd/docker
```

Indeed `/mnt/virtualmachines_ssd/` was a different partition, a different filesystem.

```
mount | grep virtualmachines | grep sdd
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/virtualmachines_ssd type ext4 (rw,nodev,nosuid,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
```

Thus,

`sudo mount -o remount,suid /mnt/virtualbox_ssd`

solved the problem! The  "ddev" docker container was able to do its job again.

```
mount | grep virtualmachines | grep sdd
/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/virtualmachines_ssd type ext4 (rw,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
```

In your case, when you can't run `sudo`.

perhaps change the entry for the filesystem in your `/etc/fstab`, and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this problem, or for anyone else having this problem, this was my solution (I had this problem too!).

Just reinstall `sudo`. Because you aren't able to use the `sudo` command, you'll have to escalate to a root command line with `su`.

```
$ su
Password:
#
```

Then

```
# apt reinstall sudo
```

No reboot necessary. You should be good to exit out of the root shell and resume you daily life.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday and I realized that the problem might be caused by a pendrive that I connected to the usb port, because the problem started soon after.

Coincidentally (or not) the pendrive had the Linux installation, even though I didn't run the executable.

So, I simply restarted the Linux and at next boot the problem vanished without a trace.

Hope it helps someone.